# onClick functions doesnt work on my Components folder next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, onclick

The problem is that my onClick functions doesn't work in my Components folder, but in my pages/index.js the button works...

This is my folder structure

- project-root/
- |-- pages/
- |   |-- api/
- |   |-- |-- app.js
- |   |-- index.js
- |   |-- _app.js
- |-- components/
- |   |-- App.js
- |   |-- ComponentX.js
- |-- redux/
- |-- styles/
- |-- public/
- |-- ...
- |-- next.config.js
- |-- package.json

This is my ComponentX.js:
**Where the button click doesn't work**

```
import '../styles/GameContainer.scss'
import useShotlessLoser from '../hooks/useShotlessLoser'
import CountDownContainer from './CountDownContainer';
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const GameBtnContainer = ({goBtnVisible, setGoBtnVisible, players}) => {

    const {shotlessLoser, handleDrawName} = useShotlessLoser()

    const handleClickToStartDraw = () => {
        console.log("entrei")
        setGoBtnVisible(false)
    }

    const handleClickOnWinner = () => {
        setGoBtnVisible(true)
    }
    

    return (
        <div className="gameBtnContainer">
            {goBtnVisible ? ( <button className={`drawBtn ${players.length === 0 ? "disabledGoButton" : ""}`} disabled={players.length === 0} onClick={() => {handleClickToStartDraw(); handleDrawName()}}>GO</button> ) : <CountDownContainer shotlessLoser={shotlessLoser} handleClickOnWinner={handleClickOnWinner}/>}
            {/* {goBtnVisible ? ( <button className="drawBtn">GO</button> ) : null} */}
        </div>
    )
}

(...)
```

My pages/index.js:
**Where the button works**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Home({ serverRenderedContent }) {
  const [clientRenderedContent, setClientRenderedContent] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch additional content on the client side
    fetch('/api/app')
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((data) => setClientRenderedContent(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => {alert("It worked")}}>Ola</button>
        <h2>Server-Side Rendered Content (Next.js)</h2>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: serverRenderedContent }} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Client-Side Rendered Content (Next.js)</h2>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: clientRenderedContent }} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch server-side rendered content during SSR
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/app');
  const serverRenderedContent = await res.text();

  // Pass data to the page component
  return {
    props: { serverRenderedContent },
  };
}

export default Home;
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Replace the body of the function with `console.log()`. Do you see anything in the console when click?

Comment: **onClick= {handleClickToStartDraw}** should be like that